# Discord.NET randomly disconnects and throws me an "Unknown opcode 9"

Tags: discord.net

Why is that? What causes that error? I have a simple code that connects to the database and returns data to the discord user. And it's literally random (I tested it when no one used it at all).

I've tried searching about it but most of the people complaining on existing bot and never actually resolved the issue.

My question is what causes the opcode 9 and what it is exactly?

Comment: What version of Discord.NET are you using?

Comment: Latest version 0.9.6

Answer (score 0):

[This is a known issue](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues/349)

[Op Code 9](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-invalid-session) stands for *Invalid Session*, which in place is used to notify clients they have an invalid session id.

This problem will not be fixed in version 0.9.6, and therefore you would have to upgrade to version 1.0.x to resolve this.